# Setting temporary Processing path for standalone PyQGIS script/application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I know how to overwrite the `TEMP` variable path from the `QGIS` Interface, but I'm having problems doing the same thing via stand-alone `Python` scripts (using `QgsApplication`).

For example, I have the following script:

```
# Prepare QGIS environment
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("E:\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('E:\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing
from processing.tools import *

# Set variables
algorithm = "saga:rastercalculator"
input = "E:/input.tif"
addInput = None
formula = "ifelse(a=0, 0/0, ifelse(a<0, 0/0, a))"
useNoData = False
dataType = 7
result = "E:/output.tif"

# Run algorithm
processing.runalg(algorithm, input, addInput, formula, useNoData,
                  dataType, result)

# Exit QGIS
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

Along with the output, the script creates `TEMP` files in the following location:

```
%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\3\processinga47e029c49534bc895c55106582f3a25\4398ed40e94f4f3285977b396abc2268\E:outputtif.sgrd
```

How can I set a different path for the `TEMP` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the temporary folder where Processing writes files by calling `os.environ` before executing the algorithm (i.e., before calling `processing.runalg()`):

On Windows:

```
import os           # This line should go in the imports section
os.environ['TMP'] = "E:\\my\\own\\tmp\\folder\\"
```

On GNU/Linux:

```
import os              # This line should go in the imports section
os.environ['TMPDIR'] = "/my/own/tmp/folder/"
```

The good part is that using `os.environ` you won't set the environment variable `TEMP/TMP/TMPDIR` permanently. It works for the current Python script/application, so you won't mess other applications up.